# Is it possible to update one Firebird database from a trigger in another Firebird database?

Tags: database, firebird

I have two firebird databases running on the same server and I want to write to a table on one of the databases from a trigger on the other database when certain actions occur. I have had a search and cannot find out if this is possible.

Can it be done either natively in firebird or via a UDF?

Thanks

Neil

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will be possible in Firebird 2.5 using the "on external" syntax.
Example:

```
EXECUTE STATEMENT('insert into table(field) values(?)')(:Param)
ON EXTERNAL 'another_server:C:\DB\DB.FDB'
AS USER 'SYSDBA' PASSWORD 'masterkey';
```

Comment: Hi Douglas

Thanks for the details. Am I right that 2.5 has not officially been released yet and is still a RC? 

Thanks

Neil